# Navigation and Tabbar Height

Tags: maui, .net-8.0

I am trying to get the height of the Tabbar and Navbar. I have set up a custom shellrenderer and can get the NavBar and StatusBar heights without issue

```
protected override void OnElementSet(Shell shell)
{
    base.OnElementSet(shell);

    int resourceId = resources.GetIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0)
    {
        int NavBarHeight = resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(resourceId) / DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Density;
    }

    resourceId = resources.GetIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0)
    {
        int StatusBarHeight = resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(resourceId) / DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Density;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out the similar syntax for the NavBar and Tabbar used in Maui to get the heights and can't find any solid information anywhere. Maybe its not possible and I am missing something obvious by any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method in the `Android.Content.Res`. Here is the link about the [Resources.GetIdentifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.res.resources.getidentifier?view=net-android-34.0). You can refer to this link for more information.

```
[Android.Runtime.Register("getIdentifier", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I", "GetGetIdentifier_Ljava_lang_String_Ljava_lang_String_Ljava_lang_String_Handler")]
public virtual int GetIdentifier (string? name, string? defType, string? defPackage);
```